# Existence Theorem in ODE doubt in understanding the theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Theorem 1. (Existence theorem): Suppose that $f(x, y)$ is a continuous function in some region

$$R = \{(x, y) : |x − x_0| ≤ a, |y − y_0| ≤ b\}\qquad  a, b > 0$$

Since $f$ is continuous in a closed and bounded domain, it is necessarily bounded in $R$, i.e., there exists $K > 0$ such that $|f(x, y)| \leq  K$ $\forall (x, y) \in R$. Then the IVP 
$$ y'=f(x,y), \qquad   y(x_0)=y$$
has at least one solution $y = y(x)$ defined in the interval $|x − x_0| \leq  \alpha$ where $α = \min(a , b/K )$.

> Why is the interval for finding solution $x=\min(a,b/K)$? Particularly why
>   is there $b/k$ and not just $b$?

Comment: Have you looked at the proof of the theorem?

Comment: Take $y' \equiv 2$, $y(0) = 0$, $a = b = 1$, and look what happens.