# Exisence and unicity for Cauchy Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

i have the following theorem:

> Let the Cauchy problem 
>   $$
> y'=f(x,y),~~ y(x_0)= y_0
> $$
>   in 
>   $$
> R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x-x_0| \leq a, |y-y_0| \leq b\}
> $$
>   If $f$ is continuous and bounded in $R$ such as $\forall (x,y) \in R: |f(x,y)| \leq M$ and if $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous and bounded in $R$ then the Cauchy problem for $f,x_0,y_0$ admits a unique solution in the interval $|x-x_0| \leq \alpha$ with $\alpha = \min(a, b/M)$.

My question is why the specific choice $\alpha= \min(a,b/M)$? For exemple why we don't take $\alpha= \min(a,b)$?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Existence Theorem in ODE doubt in understanding the theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703645/existence-theorem-in-ode-doubt-in-understanding-the-theorem) (closed as off-topic).

Comment: the post who show me are closed withut answer. Can you help me please

Comment: Look at my comment there.

Comment: Yes i read it, but it's an particular case. My question is in general why we choose $\alpha= \min(a,b/M)$ why $b/M$ exactly? Please

Comment: My example just allows to understand what happens if we take $\alpha = \min(a, b)$, that is, $1$, instead of $\alpha = \min(a, b/M)$, that is, $1/2$.  Can you draw a picture?

Comment: But how we prouve thar $\min(a,b/M)$ is the best choice?

Comment: Take $a = b = 1$, $x' \equiv A$, where $A > 1$.  Then $M = A$.  $\alpha$ must be $\le a = 1$.  But if you take $\alpha > b/M = 1/A$ then the graph of the solution, that is, of the function $x(t) = A t$, $t \in [-\alpha, \alpha]$, sticks out: for $t \in (1/A, \alpha)$ the value of the function is $> b$.  And this is an example showing that $\alpha = \min(a, b/M)$ is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image may say more than a thousand words:

[image]

With the given data and assumptions you can only make claims on the part of a solution that is inside the rectangle $R$. As to what part of the solution, if it exists, can be guaranteed to be in $R$,
you only know that $$\|y(x)-y_0\|\le \int_{x_0}^x\|f(s,y(x))\|\,dx\le M\,|x-x_0|.$$ For this "butterfly" bound to restrict the solution to $R$ you need to restrict $x$ so that $M\,|x-x_0|\le b$ in addition to the restriction $|x-x_0|\le a$. Thus
$$
|x-x_0|\le α=\min(a,b/M).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much